# Dispatch method does not pass a variable to store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to hand over variable from my component to store.
In component methods i write:

```
 methods:{
    push(){
        let message = "hi"
        this.$store.dispatch('test', message)
    }
 }
```

Then in index.js:

```
actions: {
  test({dispatch},{test}){
    console.log(test)
  },}
```

And in console i have - undefined

Comment: please take a look at the documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't destruct the dispatch payload <del>`{test}`</del> unless the  `message` parameter has a field called `test`:

```
actions: {
  test({dispatch},test){
    console.log(test)
  },}
```